# Codemagic static Pages: Skip publishing to my_app.codemagic.app: no static content was generated

Tags: codemagic

I am trying to publish the web version of my flutter app to Codemagic static Pages. I added a subdomain name and enabled the checkbox, but I get this line in the publishing logs:

```
Skip publishing to my_app.codemagic.app: no static content was generated
```

If I try to access the webpage `https://my_app.codemagic.app` I get:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>No such object: codemagic-app/my_app/index.html</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the "Building Web" step generated files and was finished without any warnings.

if "Building Web" step was skipped probably you don't have `web` folder in your repository

UPDATE:
Also check if your subdomain name doesn't contain special characters and is a valid domain name. if domain name is not valid, you will see `NoSuchKey` message in your browser even publishing step ran fine.

Comment: I had the step properly running and the publishing step ran fine too. But the URL gives me the same issue NoSuchKey. Any ideas?

Comment: check if your app name doesn't contain special characters and is a valid domain name

Comment: perfect, thanks a ton! the url started with a number and when I changed the url, it worked!